# How to send a photo over network with Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, command, rpc, data-transfer, unity-networking

I am trying to show the players Facebook profile picture each other when they are playing vs game. I tried to send the picture with `[Command]` and `[ClientRpcCall]` attributes but do not work. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's trivial to google an answer to this question.

To get you started something like ...

```
[RPC]
void SendTextures(byte[] receivedByte){
 receivedTexture = null;
 receivedTexture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
 receivedTexture.LoadImage(receivedByte);
 GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = receivedTexture;
 }
```

Just google for 100s of full examples and discussions.

Here's a huge discussion with many full scripts and so on

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/sync-texture-over-network.76538/

Try googling,

> Unity3D send image over RPC
>
> Unity3D send PNG over RPC
>
> Unity3D texture RPC

and so on

Comment: Is this line necessary? `receivedTexture = null;`

Comment: that's a great question @AaronFranke - to be honest i don't know off the top of my head.  (Unity systems change all the time.)  Try it.